# Inverse of a Function with Complex Variables

Tags: functions, complex-numbers, inverse, isometry

I'm taking Abstract Algebra, and we're currently covering isometries of the Real and Complex plane. I'm going through and studying for our first midterm, and I'm working on a problem that asks to show that the composition of two functions composed with their inverses is a translation. The question gives the two functions $f(z)$ and $g(z)$, where $f(z) = (1+i)z + (1-i)$. How does one find the inverse of a function with complex variables? Or am I just overthinking it and the answer is not as hard as I think it is?

Comment: Your knowledge on algebra will continue to work for complex numbers. Which means, you can just solve $w = f(z) = (1+i)z + (1-i)$ with respect to $z$.

Answer (score 2):

As Sangchul Lee says, you find the inverse of a function of a complex variable exactly like you do a function of a complex variable.  What I would do, since I prefer to have both "function" and "inverse function" as function of z, is write the equation as w= (1+i)z+ (1-i) and then swap w and z: z= (1+ i)w+ (1-i) and solve for w.

Comment: Again, correct me if I'm wrong, but can I treat $f(z) = (1+i)z +(1-i)$ as $f(z) = \alpha z + \beta$, letting $\alpha,\beta$ be appropriately set, and solve for $w = f(z) = \alpha z + \beta$?